# Which informations belong on every page

Tags: header-footer, typography, best-practices

I finished my first thesis last summer and I was wondering: "What can I do better next time?". Since I'm a fan of simple styles, I thought about maybe removing content from the header (I placed the current section name on every odd page, the chapter name on every even). But then a reader, who just wants to find a specific section in the document, who does know the book good enough to not need the table of content, can profit from such 'meta data'.

My question is: Which informations should be placed on every page for the different kinds of documents (naturally a presentation needs other 'meta data' than a book or an article in journal).

I know, this question seems to be opinion based and not directly directed to TeX and Friends, but this is something every (La)TeX user has to think about at least once and I truly believe there is a set of best practices concerning this question.

Comment: IMHO Since you are a fan of simple styles, standard classes (book, report, article) are fine. I don't know about presentations.

Comment: Please ask this question on [graphicdesign.sx](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) (I've flagged it for migration, but AFAIK we don't migrate to graphicdesign).

Comment: Another place where this could be asked is *academia.SE* but i guess it will be opinion-based as well.

Answer (score 3):

The question is opinion-based -- I will provide an opinion-based answer

- Pagenumber (either in the header or in the footer), exception: Part/chapter start pages/titlepage
- Section title/chapter title in the header
- A copyright statement for special sections/document
- A statement that this document was produced with `\LaTeXe` (or `ConTeXt`, or `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX` or any other flavor of TeX/LaTeX`) in order to show the Word dominated world that there's (most time) a better variant ;-)

For presentations I would prefer the same navigation elements as `beamer` provides (the feature, not the style ;-) (just for example)